# Pandas: Short summary of data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, summary

I currently use following function to inspect the distribution of data in a column that contains binary data (Example here https://pastebin.com/QpWfREYB).

```
print(pd.value_counts(df['binary']).apply(lambda x: x/len(data['label'])*100))

print(pd.value_counts(df['binary']).apply(lambda x: x))
```

**Output:**

```
A    65.466667
B    34.533333
Name: label, dtype: float64
A    7856
B    4144
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Is there a simple way to get an output like:

```
A   7856    (65.67%)
B   4144    (65.67%)
Sum 12000   (100.00%)
```

?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Hope that can help: [https://pastebin.com/QpWfREYB](https://pastebin.com/QpWfREYB)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of both Series, add new row and last add `()` to last column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/QpWfREYB', sep='\s+')
print (df.head())
  binary
0      A
1      A
2      A
3      A
4      A


a = pd.value_counts(df['binary'])
b = a.div(len(df)).mul(100).round(2)
#same as
#b = pd.value_counts(df['binary'], normalize=True).mul(100).round(2)


df = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1, keys=('x','y'))
df.loc['Sum'] = df.sum()
df['y'] = '(' + df['y'].astype(str) + '%)'
print (df)

           x         y
A     7856.0  (65.47%)
C     4144.0  (34.53%)
Sum  12000.0  (100.0%)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Though I'm a bit surprised there's no native function in pandas to do that. .describe didn't really help here..

Comment: Yes, I a bit modify solution for not double call function ;)